# braidings on super vector space

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, braidings

I want to show that $Vec_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}(\mathbb{C})$ has exactly 2 braidings

I was able to find this(Example 2.14):

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super+vector+space

Is there a simpler way to go about it, even if it less rigorous

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3770909/502324

Comment: Example 1.7 in http://mtm.ufsc.br/~ebatista/2016-1/Maringa.pdf deals with the general case of a $G$-graded space. From there you just need to know the group cohomology of $\mathbb Z_2$, for instance see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_cyclic_group:Z2